# Mock void method requires Void

Tags: java, mockito

I have the following line in the test that I'm trying to write:

```
when(service.check(anyInt())).thenThrow(new Exception(""));
```

the problem with this is that I get an error telling:

> Required type: Void
> provided: void

and the method has the return type void:

> ```
> public void check(int Id) {
>     //DO RANDOM STUFF
>
> }
> ```

How can I get around this?

Comment: Have you tried changing `public void check(int Id)` to `public Void check(int Id)`?

Comment: Why should I do that? I want to understand what is going on, not change stuff randomly